# How to cache the static java scripts in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, caching

I want to cache 3-4 scripts which is called in master page , how can i do that , any suggestions or tutorial will be help full.

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static files such as javascripts and CSS are already cached by clients browsers. So no need to do anything special. Simply reference them as usual: `<script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>`.